# Can't access layers in auxiliary output route

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

Source Code: https://github.com/IAmSuyogJadhav/3d-mri-brain-tumor-segmentation-using-autoencoder-regularization/blob/master/Example_on_BRATS2018.ipynb

Target : Brain Tumor Detection, MRI DATA

I want to use the above model and public mri data(brats) to make a model to segment brain tumor. 
I decided to use transfer learning method, so trained the above model with brats 2019 data.

Then, to keep the layers untrainable except for the 2 last layers(please refer to the below image),[image] i tried to run this code:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

But i found **i couldn't access the last layer of VAE part(marked bottom of the image).** Because model.layers doesn't include the layers of VAE part. 
How could i access the layers in VAE part(auxiliary output route)? Or is there any way to keep the layers of VAE part untrainable?

Answer (score 1):

The source code had a problem.
It defined a model with only one output, so i could not access the VAE branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to freeze all layers in your model except the last two layers, and your model has a VAE part, you need to:

1. Set all layers as untrainable initially:
   for layer in model.layers:
   layer.trainable = False
2. Access the layers in the VAE part and set them as untrainable:
   vae_layers = model.get_layer('vae_encoder').layers
   for layer in vae_layers:
   layer.trainable = False
3. Finally, set the last two layers as trainable:
   for layer in model.layers[-2:]:
   layer.trainable = True

This way, only the last two layers become trainable, and the VAE layers remain untrainable.